# After installing garuda and rebooting stuck in boot screen

Tags: arch-linux, grub, garuda-linux

Hello everyone first time arch /garuda user here. I just partitioned my windows laptop to install garuda and finish the installation process. When printed to reboot I did so and was stuck on a loading screen. When I went i to grub is said.

```
/new_root: can't find UUID=7137....
```

After it dropped me into an emergency shell I was hit with a

```
sh: can't access tty: job control turned off
```

can anyone explain to me what is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Does anyone know I have asked around and known knows I'm pretty sure its an ASUS issue but I have no clue